# How to forwardRef selected value from React-Select to react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form and trying to get selected value from custom react-select component, by following the guide: [UseFormMethods](https://react-hook-form.com/ts#UseFormMethods).

The problem is that no value is being passed to the form.

Im doing the following:

```
interface Option {
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

interface Props {
  name: string;
  options: Option[];
  error?: string;
  label?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  clearable?: boolean;
}

const MySelect = React.forwardRef<ReactSelect, Props>(
  (
    { name, error, options, label, placeholder, disabled, clearable, ...rest },
    ref
  ) => (
    <>
      {label && <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>}
      <ReactSelect
        id={name}
        name={name}
        ref={ref}
        options={options}
        placeholder={placeholder || ""}
        isDisabled={disabled}
        isClearable={clearable}
        {...rest}
      />
      {error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </>
  )
);

export default MySelect;
```

Full code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-star-4jyvf).
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you considered to use `Controller`?

https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller

we actually have a working version on the doc as well:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-controller-qsd8r

```
<Controller
  as={ReactSelect}
  options={[
    { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
    { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
    { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
  ]}
  name="ReactSelect"
  isClearable
  control={control}
/>
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for the long delay. I changed the App component a bit and added the select field as Controller just as you said, so I was able to solve the case. Thank you very much!! 